# How to integrate code of iphone application in my android application?

Tags: android

I am working on a project and i want to integrate some of the code of an iphone application those are in c++ and objective c in my application.. I know there is a android ndk which make me able to use c/c++ code in android.. But whether it is useful for objective c and c++ or not.If you have any idea, Share with me..Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) works well with both C and C++.

Sadly, Android does not have an ObjectiveC runtime built in, so your ObjectiveC code will not run. Depending on complexity, you may or may not have luck with [third party support](http://code.google.com/p/android-gcc-objc2-0/) for adding this though.